# Decoding the ID Token Yahoo sign in

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-api

I hope someone can help, I am trying to get user data(name,email,etc) from yahoo sign in and I did exactly what doc say [Oauth2 Yahoo](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/openid_connect/getting_started.html)

everything is fine, but in the last step the docs say after ur post request (sending the correct data) you will get this fields

```
access_token
id_token    
expires_in 
token_type 
refresh_token
xoauth_yahoo_guid
```

but my result is

```
object(stdClass)[293]
 public 'access_token' => string'LqV8XJaYvV.otOTRWAqkUKOApYpYi9Ewc.TrISqHPBC5TYjbgNxTXutpDUpLQAhthqM6CSHBLw.zzGh88iN.OIg.yLebST6JZDuRmRgJJMpOEzhOAxDhQosKVmFayt8YDVXiQSlT23qXMvJrTNYa8rKcofyrkU3TGMUySkjEAuS2667kDJUsCVkYWGUi5nnK.ZyShLosS.sygv0.VCAvONAvZeUcfptHCp9sJ0XVnwwXrrKYLOIFQMogdZYFc8YHz7MjAHXsxK1y4DZR6aEbSj.1ZGUiSnV7MEJ73SQEan8xakFs7posnyQo1WZOcbOnYZ_TQvcPkT1QQs96xngbkW.QbFKU4BVnZ0qbkXTcdsK3GEXXJrrliNOdxIesBA5joWYQKCZcr4aq42lEdedERx9OYggPwlqM5Xy1Mr5N._rHIAnOS0tVG_TNUHvRIGuXaRp9DeIBz9PKLWqRYWjwF0zFnVaE9iRpufpn.ZzRkx7UZlWS6TlZEn7FjEOXu6CJ'...
 public 'refresh_token' => string'AJbEoFk51gPXOEgzJPsMhCSbmK9VFFaGydxb925fxB4mi5Pfm98-' 
 public 'expires_in' => int 3600
 public 'token_type' => string 'bearer' 
 public 'xoauth_yahoo_guid' => string 'E7HLX6HSEMQRFGE3HL3ANLH4HM'
```

how you can see i am not getting id_token any idea??

Answer (score 0):

For getting user data use your `xoauth_yahoo_guid` and check this documentation of [yahoo GUID](https://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/ysocial_apis-guids.html).
No need to use `id_token`

Call the HTTP GET operation on the following URI:

```
http://social.yahooapis.com/progrss/v1/users.guid(E7HLX6HSEMQRFGE3HL3ANLH4HM)/profile?format=json&.imgssl=1
```

Or use YQL Web Service:
[YQL Console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2A%20from%20social.profile%20where%20guid%20=%20me#h=select%20*%20from%20social.profile%20where%20guid%20%3D%20me)